# SharePoint Alternate Access Mapping Connection Reset

Tags: iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, windows-server, sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint 2019 Publishing Site intended for internet-facing that works fine and good on localhost while building it.

However, when modifying the AAM and putting the correct URL for internet when I try to access it I get a Connection Reset Error for no clear reason.

I am sure that my Hostname is correct and configured fine as it works on any non SharePoint site, but for SP sites is starts giving this weird error. Also, I am adding the URL on AAM and on IIS as well. But when configuring AAM things do not work on the configured AAM neither on localhost nor on public anon machine.

After checking the logs I have seen the following warning:

```
Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services are accessing the site http://web-01 with the URL http://{myurl}.  This may cause incorrect links to be stored or returned to users.  If this is expected, add the URL http://{myurl}as an AAM response URL.  For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=114854"/>
```

However, this warning is for SharePoint -80 which is the web app that comes by default with SP but I am not using. I have my new SP web app on custom port and mapped to an AAM but it seems that it takes the AAM Internet link and use it with SharePoint-80 in a weird way.

Sometimes I get this also:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Date: Mon, 18 Sep 2023 10:51:24 GMT
Connection: close
```

I have checked few logs and did not find anything useful.

Also trying to use Curl:

```
*   Trying {ip}:443...
* Connected to {url} (ip) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* using HTTP/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: {url}
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404
< Date: Tue, 19 Sep 2023 08:48:22 GMT
< Content-Length: 101
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
< SPRequestGuid: d2ecdba0-c473-8098-1809-242a3e3ceffd
< request-id: d2ecdba0-c473-8098-1809-242a3e3ceffd
< X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
< SPRequestDuration: 46
< SPIisLatency: 0
< X-Powered-By: nosniff
< MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.10337: 1; RequireReadOnly
<
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Date: Tue, 19 Sep 2023 08:48:21 GMT
Connection: close
* Connection #0 to host {url} left intact
```

Comment: Check the Windows Event Viewer log for any SharePoint-related errors or warnings, which may provide more information about the problem.

Comment: Just added the AAM warning which seems not related to this SP app.

Comment: Also, note that the SharePoint -80 is mapping to Computer Name for the zone Default.